# Any ideas on why os.system() could fail?

Tags: python, cmd, os.system

I have recently installed python on a new computer. 
I cannot find the reason why `os.system()` fails, or could fail.
I experimented with `os.popen()` and subprocess in my main script, and this does not solve the issue.

Mostly concerned though why this simple test of `os.system()` fails to begin with.

in cmd prompt:

```
>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v. 1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import os
>>> os.system("dir")
-1
>>> os.system("cmd /c dir")
-1
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call("dir", shell=True)
Traceback ...
...
WindowsError: [Error 2] System could not locate file
>>> exit()
dir
(list of files)
```

I used dir as example, but the same thing happens when I call any other program that is included in the system path. It will run directly from cmd line but not through os.system or subprocess.

Comment: The code you post works for me with the same version of Python under Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

`dir` is not an executable, it's a `cmd.exe` command.

Try:

```
os.system("cmd /c dir")
```

or

```
subprocess.call("dir", shell=True)
```

Comment: No idea (and I wasn't trying to imply anything .. :) .. just curious. Perhaps it depends on the environment (flavor of Windows?) since I'm running the same exact version of Python.

Comment: Cygwin puts a `dir.exe` in the path.

Comment: That's the funny thing, this works for me in Xp on a computer at work. It works for me on my pc at home on windows 7. But it does not work on my laptop on windows 7, and really wouldn't know what settings I should check.

Comment: @RodrigoQueiro hmm .. I don't think I have Cygwin installed (unless it came bundled with some other software I installed). Also, I tried to search for `dir.exe` and couldn't find it ... very odd.

Comment: @Levon you can use wh.py by @ned-batchelder to see where `dir` is coming from. http://nedbatchelder.com/code/utilities/wh_py.html

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. As I suspected it was something to do with the environment variables.

Though I added all the programs I needed to `Path`, I never took a look at the ComSpec environment variable.

Apparently, I added

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
```

to `comspec` in addition to the default

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
```

I'm still not sure why, but this causes problems if you want to call files through `os.system` or `subprocess` or `os.popen`.

The solution was to either add all the paths from Path to `ComSpec` as well, or simply remove the path to the Java binary.

When this is done, everything works fine, (even dir).

Comment: Feel free to explain WHY this is so. :)